# sci-kit SVM multi-class classification with unseen label

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

is there any possibility to configure an svm classifier from sci-kit such that:

1.) the svm classifier is trained with examples from 0,...,n - 1

2.) If none of the single classifiers (one-vs-rest) delivers a positive result (class membership), then the output is a designated label n which means "none of them"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction, the OvR multiclass wrapper `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier` selects the maximum `decision_function` output or the maximum `predict_proba` to be decisive of predicted class. This means that there will always be a predicted class.

If you wanted e.g. to predict "None of these" when `decision_function` / `predict_proba` all stay under a certain threshold (for all OvR problems), then you would have to write this estimator yourself, but could get inspiration from the code of `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier` and just modify the decision logic.